# XPATH ignore specific div class name

Tags: html, xpath

```
<div class="rowh">Engine and Drive Train
  </div>
  <a name="anc0"></a>
  <div class="optexrow oid0 row " data-oid="0">
    <div class="key">Engine Size
    </div>
    <div class="value">998 cc 
    </div>
    <div class="cf">
    </div>
  </div>
```

This query:

```
//div[contains(preceding-sibling::div[@class='rowh'][1],'Engine and Drive Train')]/div
```

Gives me:

```
    1.Engine Size
    2.998 cc
    3.
    4.Gears
    5.5
    6.
    7.Number of Valves
    8.12
    9.
    10.Transmission
    11.Manual
```

How do I ignore this empty div:

```
<div class="cf">
```

Or not look for it in the first place? I know it's something to do with "NOT" but I cannot seem to be able to nestle this in.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `normalize-space()` function strips leading and trailing white-space from a string, replaces sequences of whitespace characters by a single space, and returns the resulting string.

then check length of string using `string-length()` function in XPath. string-length() function returns the number of character in a string.

the final query will be as following:

```
//div[contains(preceding-sibling::div[@class='rowh'][1],'Engine and Drive Train')]/div[string-length(normalize-space(text())) > 0]
```

or shorten by using `normalize-space()` only it as following:

```
//div[contains(preceding-sibling::div[@class='rowh'][1],'Engine and Drive Train')]/div[normalize-space()]
```